# Space Group names

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In space groups, how do know if which axis/planes the glide/mirror/rotations are perpendicular to.

For example in Pnma, 
how do we know that a-glide plane is perp to c-axis, n-glide plane perp to a-axis, and mirror plane is perp to b axis?

Comment: @IvanNeretin So for Ama2, we would have _m(⊥a),a(⊥b),2(c⊥)?

Comment: 2 is an axis, not a plane, hence it is _parallel_ to c.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks, if you want to post those comments as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite simple, if we are talking of orthorhombic groups. The elements corresponding to the cell directions $a,b,с$ follow in the same order as $a, b, с$ in the alphabet. Here by *"corresponding to"* we mean *"perpendicular to"* in case of a plane or *"parallel to"* in case of an axis.

So this is what $\rm{Pnma}$ consists of:

- glide plane $n\,(\perp a)$,
- mirror plane $m\,(\perp b)$,
- glide plane $a\,(\perp с)$.

Another example: $\rm{Ama2}$ has

- mirror plane $m\,(\perp a)$,
- glide plane $a\,(\perp b)$,
- axis $2\,(\parallel с)$.

Yet another example: $\rm{P222_1}$ has rotation axes 2 along $a$ and $b$, and a screw axis $2_1$ along $с$.

Things get hairy when we reach the tetragonal groups, but that's another story.